# Angular 2 reference in Json

Tags: json, angular, typescript, reference, ionic2

I'm working on Ionic2 project, I want to create a model and save it to a json file, to read it later to build again my model. My issue is about object reference , example :

When I build a json with object A, B, C :

```
let A = new A();
let B = new B();
let C = new C();

A.B = B;
A.C = C;
B.C = C;
```

So my json is like :

```
A : {
   B : { C : { ... } },
   C : { ... }
}
```

At this moment C, A.C and B.C are the same object. So when I make a change in C, there is the same change in B.C and A.C.

But, when I'm saving in file, and then I read the file, objects are copies, so when I'm changing B.C, A.C stay in the old state.

So my question :

Is there any option to save references in Json file or to detect after reading same objects ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When that object is converted to a JSON string and then back again, they are no longer linked as the same object.  Additionally, there is really no way to have json *know* that a thing is a reference to another. Additionally, when you load it back from json, it doesn't even know that A, B, and C are instances of specific "classes".  They're just Plain-Old JavaScript Objects (POJOs).

If you wanted them to be instances of A, B, and C, you would need to create new instances of A, B, and C, set the values from the JSON to those objects, and then set either A.C = B.C or B.C = A.C.